# JavaFX 2.x : Plotting two different types of charts on the same graph

Tags: javafx-2, linechart, candlestick-chart

I have a financial data serie I plot as Candlestick chart: I would like to add other serie(s) as LineChart(s).

The [example from javafx example - samples - Adv candlestick chart](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/2.2/samples/Ensemble/index.html), shows a LineChart added as average as last column in data array.

I wonder if there are other ways to add LineCharts since I need to add other LineChart series to an already plotted Candlestick chart.

Thanks

Comment: No other way that I know, except maybe using a stack pane that contains both charts. Then you can play with the opacity of the chart that is on top of the other one. That's not the most elegant solution but it works and can help sometimes.